# printing contents of log file to curses screen using python

Tags: python, curses

why doesnt this work?
-- full code here... http://pastebin.com/f940nPPg

```
....snip
f = open(log, 'r')
y = 3;
x = 3;

while True:
    c = quote_window.getch() 
    if c == ord('r') or c == ord('R'):
        quote_text_window.clear()
        quote_text_window.refresh()
        for line in f:
            quote_text_window.addstr(line)
            y = y + 1
            quote_text_window.move(y, x)

    elif c == ord('q') or c == ('Q'):
        break

    stdscr.noutrefresh()
    quote_window.noutrefresh()
    quote_text_window.noutrefresh()
    curses.doupdate()
f.close()
....snip
```

i get error

```
    quote_text_window.addstr(line)
    _curses.error: addwstr() returned ERR
```

if i pass addstr() a string literal i get

```
    quote_text_window.move(y, x)
    _curses.error: wmove() returned ERR
```

i'm trying to develope a curses interface for reading log files. i'd like it to utilize ssh or something so i can read various log files from various computers in one interface. im' sure there are a ton of great programs that do this kind of thing but i thought it would be a good way to learn.
i'm new to programming, python and curses (as you can probably tell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you supply the entire code with comments included to explain certain parts you think might cause the problem? Anyways, how many lines is your log file? Because, if there are too many lines, it just doesn't run, like my terminal is 80 col and 24 lines, so if I had a log file that was 21 lines, the program doesn't work.

Comment: i added a link to patesbin. the log file i'm using is a section of kern.log only 59 lines. is there a better way to handle outputting large amounts of text? thx for responding!

Comment: you're right. a smaller file prints out. what should i do for larger files? maybe add a keyevent to just display a screen-full at a time.

Comment: No problem, one idea is that if the log file is longer than the screen, you could prompt the user to hit a key to go onto the next/previous section.

Comment: i've added key binding like C-n, and C-p to scroll the pad.

Answer (score 0):

like Cold Diamondz said the text file cant be larger than the window but if you use a pad you can call a large file and tell the pad what dimensions to refresh. 
check out pads 
    http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html